# How can I full logout from Firebase facebook? SwiftUI

Tags: ios, firebase, facebook, authentication, swiftui

I have the following problem:
I set up a Facebook login with a firebase. The first time I logged in with Facebook successfully. I also have a logout button that logs out , to log in through other methods , but is's not full log out.

When re-entering through Facebook, a window pops up on which there are two buttons: "Continue" and "Cancel". There is also an undo button in the upper left corner of the pop-up screen.

When I press cancel on any button, or try to swipe the screen down, my app crashes.

Screenshot of crash:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uiYt.png)

Code:

```
import SwiftUI
import FBSDKLoginKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

struct FaceBookLoginView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> FaceBookLoginView.Coordinator {
        return FaceBookLoginView.Coordinator()
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, LoginButtonDelegate {
        func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton, didCompleteWith result: LoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error?) {
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
            let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: AccessToken.current!.tokenString)
            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    print("Error in line up")
                    return
                }
                print("Facebook Sign In")
            }
        }
        
        func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton) {
            try! Auth.auth().signOut()
            let loginManager = LoginManager()
            loginManager.logOut() // this is an instance function 
        }
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<FaceBookLoginView>) -> FBLoginButton {
        let view = FBLoginButton()
        view.permissions = ["email"]
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: FBLoginButton, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<FaceBookLoginView>) { }
}
```

I tried:
Reinstall application
Clean build folder.
Log in to facebook on the same simulator via safari, log in and log out

Please , help me full log out!
Thanks!

Comment: You can not log the user out of Facebook itself, if they were logged in before they logged into your app already.

Comment: @CBroe , But first I went to Facebook through my application, and only then I tried to go through safari. Now I can't change my Facebook account inside my application?